# Multiplicative inverse in polynomials mod p

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the multiplicative inverse of $1+2x$ in $\mathbb{Z_8}[x]$

My work:

I know that since $1$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z_8}[x]$ and $2$ is nilpotent of index $3$, $1 + 2x$ has a multiplicative inverse. Now $(1+2x)(a+bx)=1$ 
and from here I arrive at a system with the following conditions: $a=1$, $b+2a=0$ and $2b=0$. 
 Cómo se pronuncia
But with that I do not reach anything concrete and I think there is an error in my calculation because I am not taking into account what happens with the zero dividers. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: You don't need to solve linear systems. Just recall how you proved that $1 + $ nilpotent is invertible. It's done through an explicit formula, and all you need to do is to plug $2x$ into that formula.

Comment: This is one of those times calculus can inform algebra.  What is $$\frac{1}{1+2x}$$ expanded as a geometric series?

Comment: @darijgrinberg 1+2=3 is a unit. 
in which formula do I have to put 2x? and because?

Comment: Not my area of expertise but $\frac 1{1-r}= 1+r+r^2+...$ so wouldn't $\frac 1{1+2x} = 1-2x + 4x^2 - 8x^3+....\equiv 1-2x+4x^2$.  And.... lessee.... $(1-2x+4x^2)(1+2x)=1+8x^3\equiv 1$.  seems to work....

Comment: @HendrikMatamoros: You're referencing a theorem stating that if $n$ is nilpotent, then $1+n$ is inverse. How did you prove this theorem?

Comment: @fleablood 
I already saw it, thank you very much. But one question, how did you know that what had to be replaced in the series was precisely $2x$?

Comment: How could I not? Brian asked how to express $\frac 1{1+2x}$ as a geometric series. I didn't necessarily know *why* he was asking but it's well known $\frac 1{1-r}=1+r+r^2+....$ so just needed to solve for $r$ knowing wanting $\frac 1{1-r} = \frac 1{1+2x}$. How could I *not* know that I'd replace $r$ with $-2x$? Even if I didn't know formula I could have done long division. $1+2x$ into $1$ is $1$. That leaves $-2x$.  $1+2x$ to $-2x$ is $-2x$.  Leaves $4x^2$.  $1+2x$ into $4x^2$ is $4x^2$ and that leave $8x^3\equiv 0\pmod 8$.  The *hard* part is knowing ahead of time that it *is* invertable.

Comment: @fleablood Well understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* If $R$ is a ring and $t\in R$ is nilpotent, then $1+t$ is a unit and its inverse is given by a *finite* geometric series.

In your case, $t=2x$ and so $t^3=0$. Thus, the inverse of $1+2x$ is $1-2x+(2x)^2$, which is easily checked.

Comment: In this case how to calculate the expression in series of $\frac{1}{1+2x}$? 
In which bibliography can I find a demonstration of that result? Was it unknown to me until now...

Comment: $1/(1-t)=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$. Put $t=-2x$ into that.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown 
I already got it! That hint was very important. Thank you. Do you know where I can read any proof of this result with geometric series?

Comment: @HendrikMatamoros The proof is elementary by just multiplying it out.

Answer (score 3):

This is just what the other answers say, but I think this is how one can remember it: If you have $1+t$ with $t \in R$ nilpotent, then you can make use of the third binomial formula:
$$(1 + t)(1 - t) = 1 - t^2$$
You see that you now have $t^2$ instead of $t$. So multiplying by $(1 + t^2)$ yields
$$ (1+t)(1-t)(1+t^2) = 1 - t^4 $$
In your example, $t = 2x$ has order $3$, so $t^4 = 0$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+2x)(a+bx+cx^2) =1$$

Solve for $a,b,c$

I have $$ a=1, b=6,c=4$$

$$(1+2x)(1+6x+4x^2) = 1+ (8)x+(16)x^2+(8)x^3 \equiv 1 (\mod 8)$$